# Adding locale.js in moment React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

i wanna add `moment-locale-ru.js` in react, and i just add `moment-locale-ru.js` in `script tag` in `index.html`, but it requires `moment`, because `react` perform after `script tag`. How properly add `locale` in `moment` `React`?

Comment: Show us some relevant code. What order are you including your script tags? Putting moment, moment-locale-ru, and then react in that order should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the github repo [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale), russian locale is already included and you can import it in your component like this:

```
import 'moment/locale/ru';
```